# What are all the start game conversations made in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

I've noticed in a video that Hanzo makes comments about Sake, and then McCree says that he prefers beer (or something like that). What are all the conversations possible?

https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4f20fk/start_of_the_game_conversations/

Comment: What's the link to reddit for?

Answer (score 1):

They are called "interactions" and it's the way the game explains in a very brief way the story behind your selected character and the one your character is interacting with.

A good example would be Sombra, you can see all of Sombra's interactions [here](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Sombra/Quotes#Interactions), you can see in those interactions Widowmaker's contempt towards Sombra because of the failed mission to kill Katya Volskaya they had alongside Reaper. You can also see how several other characters are not precisely happy with her about something.

That's exactly what those small conversations mean, they are ways to show you a bit about the story between those characters interacting.

[Here](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Heroes) you can select one of the heroes and then click on the quotation page to see every voice line they have, including the interactions.

Adding an image since the link is kind of elusive:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to all the possible interactions? I think that's what the question is asking for

Comment: Yes, I'll add the main page where you can access each character and their quotes, including the interactions.

Comment: Just like every other answer, this is link-only.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Example : the link you placed becomes dead, what purpose serves your answer ?

Comment: In that case, should I just place all of the interactions in my answer? That would be extremely long.